# An invalid syntax within an discord.py event

Tags: discord.py

```py
import discord
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.ext import commands+
from discord.utils import get
import time

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='r.', description="prefix")


@bot.event
async def on_message_delete(message):
    if(message.author != bot.user):
        else:
                deleted = message.content
                channel = bot.get_channel(657899187957923852)
                await channel.send(time + '"' + deleted + '"')
```

in the line 12 `else:` is *invalid syntax ( unknown, line 12)pylint(syntax-error)* I am trying to make it when a message that is not the bot will send to another channel that the channel id is equal to 657899187957923852.

with the imports i dont know what i have used and the ones that are necessary for this one command (edited)

Comment: Please make a clear question statement and refer to [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for information on discord.py.Also, edit the post with a screenshot of the error and what steps did you follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have some code in the block under the `if` statement.

```
@bot.event
async def on_message_delete(message):
    if(message.author != bot.user):
        return 
    else:
        deleted = message.content
        channel = bot.get_channel(657899187957923852)
        await channel.send(time + '"' + deleted + '"')
```